# How to combine objects after warping?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using Adobe Illustrator, I would like to make an bent arrow consisting of a rectangle and a triangle. If I don't bend the arrow, I can just combine the two objects with the path-finder tool.

However, once I bent the rectangle with the warp tool, this is not possible anymore. Specifically, I can click on the "create compound shape" option of the pathfinder, but nothing happens.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Do you actually mean the Warp **tool**? Or do you mean the Warp **effect**?

Comment: @Scott - I think the OP must mean an Envelope Distort >Make with Warp effect, since using the Warp tool doesn't stop you from doing pathfinder operations.

Comment: My guess @BillyKerr is he's using `Effect > Warp` - which is very similar to the Envelopes, but not exactly the same. Most newer users never see the Envelopes for a while due to their menu position. I agree with your answer, just thought clarity couldn't hurt.

Comment: @Scott - no worries!  Yeah could be that.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator an envelope warp is an effect applied to an object, so to use the resulting warped shape with the Shape Builder or Pathfinder or Combine, you first need to select it and do *Object > Expand*, to turn the object into ordinary paths, essentially baking in the effect.